# Control requests to view and template output in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-2.0

This is a view for get all the records in the `EducationalRecord` model:

```
def all_education_resume(request):
    RESUME_INFO['view'] = 'education'
    educations_resume = EducationalRecord.objects.all().order_by('-created_date')
    template = 'resumes/all_resume.html'
    context = {'educations_resume': educations_resume, 'resume_info': RESUME_INFO}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Now, if I want to write exactly this view for other models (like job resumes, research resumes , etc.), 
I must another  view one separately.
 **My question is:**

> How can I get a view for all these requests, so first check the URL of
>   the request and then do the relevant query?  How can I control URL
>   requests in my views?

**My other question is exactly the same as my first question,with this difference:**

> control view that must render in specific template.In other words,in
>   second question the ratio between the template and the view is instead
>   of the ratio of the view to the url or how to create a template for
>   multiple views  (for example, for a variety of database resume
>   resumes, I have a template)  and then, depending on which view render,
>   the template output is different.

**I have implemented these two issues as follows:**

1. I wrote a view for each of request!
2. In each view, I set the value of `RESUME_INFO['view']`, and then I've checked it in a template page and specified the corresponding template.

***What is the best solution to these two questions?***

Comment: You can see the `request.path`, but it is not a good idea at all to handle all these tasks by the same view. You can use a cbv `ListView` that will remove most of the boilerplate code however.

Comment: But all of this task is same! all of their differences is the name of their `model`! How can I use one `ListView` to handle these same tasks? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @mstafarahnama: you just write `class ModelAListView(ListView): model=MyModel template='some_templatefora.html'` so these are three lines per view. By using a unified listview, you will only generate more trouble, since the template might be different, and eventually you might want to have some access control for some lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get a view for all these requests, so first check the URL of the request and then do the relevant query? How can I control URL requests in my views?

You can access `request.path`, or you can let the `url(..)`s pass a parameter with kwargs that holds a reference to the model for example, but this is usually bad design. Typically if you use different models, you will likely have to order these different as well, filter these differently, render these differently, etc. If not, then this typically indicates that something is wrong with the modeling.

You can however make use of [*class-based views* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), to remove as much boilerplate as posssible. Your view looks like a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), by using such view, and patching where necessary, we can omit most of the "*boilerplate*" code:

```
# app/views.py

from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class MyBaseListView(ListView):
    resume_info = None
    template = 'resumes/all_resume.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['resume_info'] = {'view': self.resume_info}
        return context
```

In the individual listviews, you then only need to specify the `resume_info` and the `model` or `queryset` to render it with the `'all_resume.html'` template, for example:

```
# app/views.py

# ...

class EducationalResumeView(MyBaseListView):
    queryset = EducationalRecord.objects.order_by('-created_date')
    resume_info = 'education'

class OtherModelView(MyBaseListView):
    model = OtherModel
    resume_info = 'other_info'
```

So we can here use inheritance to define common things only once, and use it in multiple views. In case we need to change something in a specific view, we can override it at that level.

In the `urls.py`, you define such view with the [**`.as_view()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view). For example:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import EducationalResumeView, OtherModelView

urlpatterns = [
    path('education/', EducationalResumeView.as_view()),
    path('other/', OtherModelView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I looking for! Is it possible to answer my second question? @willem-van-onsem

Comment: @mostafarahnama: well here we will use the same template (`'resumes/all_resume.html'`) for all subclasses of `MyBaseListView`, if you want to change it in a subclass, you only have to specify another `template = ...` for that class. All subclasses of that class will inherit that one then.

Comment: Is it possible to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56200282/developing-shopping-cart-with-sessions-in-django) question too? @willem-van-onsem